# Error when integrating SQL Server 2012 reporting service with SharePoint Server 2010

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I have a VM with SQL Server 2012 installed. Another VM for SharePoint Server 2010. The SharePoint is configured using SQL Server 2012. All works well except for reporting. I added features for SharePoint reporting by running installation wizard. Link referred is: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/gg492276.aspx#bkmk_install_SSRS_sharedservice. Completed the Part 1: Install Reporting Services Report Server in SharePoint mode, successfully. Moving to Part 2: Install and Start the Reporting Services SharePoint Service, the cmdlet  Install-SPRSService when run in SharePoint 2010 Management Shell, I hit with an error: The term 'Install-SPRSService' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program... How can this be solved? Is there any feature in SharePoint that I need to activate before running this?

Comment: did you install both reporting services sharepoint and reporting services add-in?

Comment: Yes I did. Both Reporting Services – SharePoint and Reporting Services add-in for SharePoint 2010 products were installed.

Comment: did you install them on Sharepoint VM?

Comment: No I did in VM for SQL Server 2012. I added both these features to SQL Server 2012.

Answer (score 1):

Please install everything what is mentioned in the link on the Sharepoint VM

Comment: I have exactly followed the link

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, i resolved it by installing “Reporting services Add-in for SharePoint” from SQL media and "SQL Server 2012 Service Pack 1" on top of it.